# undefined method base_uri on httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I am using httparty to get create a gem to allow user to get an auth_token from a site.

I need to do POST method session:

```
POST https://www.mysite.io/api/v1/sessions
```

followed by email and password (both are strings) in the `body`

Here is what I have:

```
require 'httparty'

class Gemname
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "https://www.mysite.io/api/v1/sessions"

  def initialize(email, password)
    response = self.class.post(self.base_uri, body: {"email": email, "password": password}) 
    raise InvalidStudentCodeError.new() if response.code == 401
    @auth_token = response["auth_token"]
  end

end
```

Gemname works fine on irb. However, I am having trouble entering my email and password. Whenever I do `Gemname.new("myemail@email.com", "mypassword")`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method`base_uri'` error.

How can I fix my code so that I HTTParty recognize my email and password to be passed down to `self.class.post` properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.base_uri` in your example refers to a member of the instance being constructed while HTTParty's `base_uri` is a class method.

You can access it with:

```
self.class.base_uri
```

Comment: That solves it! I now see a different error `Gemname::InvalidStudentCodeError`, but at least httparty recognizes my inputs. Thanks!